# Ansible override a group var from extra vars flag

Tags: ansible

passing a `-e "@globals.yml"` flag into `ansible-playbook` overwrites the variables for all hosts. How to do so for only a particular group? For example:

```
.
├── README.md
├── ansible.cfg
├── globals.yml
├── group_vars
│   ├── all.yml
│   ├── g1.yml
│   └── g2.yml
├── inventory.yml
├── out.log
└── site.yml
```

`inventory.yml`:

```yaml
all:
  hosts:
    host01:
      ansible_host: host1
    host02:
      ansible_host: host2
    host03:
      ansible_host: host3
  children:
    g1:
      hosts:
        host01:
    g2:
      hosts:
        host02:
```

`group_vars/all.yml`:

```yaml
all: this is in all.yml
```

`group_vars/g1.yml`:

```yaml
name1: group1, located in g1.yml
```

`group_vars/g2.yaml`:

```yaml
name2: group2, located in g2.yml
```

`globals.yml`:

```yaml
net_int: eno2
name1: name1 overwritten by globals.yml!
```

Running `ansible-playbook -i inventory.yml -e "@globals.yml" site.yml` overwrites `name1` for `g1` and creates `name1` for all other hosts in `all` group. Is there a way to have the extra vars only overwrite the `name1` for `g1` and not create the variable for all others?

Comment: Why would you want to introduce such complexity just to save additional playbook executions? You can solve this by running the playbook on the special group once, with the override, and run it without for the rest.

Comment: @ChenA. well this question is not about bringing complexity. Imagine a scenario where you have multiple inventories with dozens of groups that all need extra variables from ansible command line. You'd rather override all those variables at once.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to override a group variable from the command line option `-e`. From [Ansible variable precedence documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/general_precedence.html#using-e-extra-variables-at-the-command-line) :

> Values passed with -e are variables, not command-line options, and they will override configuration settings, command-line options, and playbook keywords as well as variables set elsewhere.

A warkaround would be to run your playbook on each host group individually, overriding any variable with `-e` option.